# Magento 2 - Order best sellers products by period

Tags: php, orders, products, magento2.3

For now, I'm getting my best sales like this.
I would like to be able to influence the order of my products in the collection.

In my Block :

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory;
// ...
public function __construct(Template\Context $context,CollectionFactory $bestSellersCollectionFactory)
{
    $this->bestSellersCollectionFactory = $bestSellersCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, []);
}

public function getBestSellersProducts()
{
    $collection = $this->bestSellersCollectionFactory->create()->setModel(
        'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'
    )
    ;

    return $collection;
}
// ...
```

In my template :

```
$collection = $block->getBestSellersProducts();
// improvised part that doesn't work
$collection->setPeriod('month')->setOrder('period','DESC')->load();
// result data period -> 2015,2016,2017,2018,2019...
```

The problem is that these products arrive in a chronologically increasing way and I would like the opposite of course  :)

Comment: Have you tried doing `$collection->getSelect()->order('period DESC')`? Looking in the Bestsellers collection class it looks like that's how it sets the sort order, so that might override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this method in this class : `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory`

```
/**
 * Make select object for date boundary
 *
 * @param string $from
 * @param string $to
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select
 */
protected function _makeBoundarySelect($from, $to)
{
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $cols = $this->_getSelectedColumns();
    $cols[$this->getOrderedField()] = 'SUM(' . $this->getOrderedField() . ')';
    $select = $connection->select()->from(
        $this->getResource()->getMainTable(),
        $cols
    )->where(
        'period >= ?',
        $from
    )->where(
        'period <= ?',
        $to
    )->group(
        'product_id'
    )->order(
        $this->getOrderedField() . ' DESC' // 'period DESC'
    )->limit(
        $this->_ratingLimit
    );

    $this->_applyStoresFilterToSelect($select);

    return $select;
}
```

Or you can try this

```
$collection->setPeriod('month')->getSelect()->order('period DESC');
```

Good luck !